# Python - MySql access for inserting data into db

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-models

I have created a Django application.Now i am trying to populate some data into SQL database tabel EmployeeDetails, using normal python script. But i am not able to insert data into db. I guess its because my db is not connecting with this external python script. I am new with Python, so please help me to solve this.This is my python script :

```
import MySQLdb
    db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password123","employee")
    def dumpdata():
        userName = 'John'
        designation = 'Software Engineer'
        employeeID = '2312'
        contactNumber = '9495321257'
        project = 'cricket'
        dateOfJoin = '2009-10-10'
        EmployeeDetails(userName,designation,employeeID,contactNumber,project,dateOfJoin).save()
```

My settings.py in Django is :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'employee',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

My final need is to put the insertion code in a loop and populate as many data i need into db. Somebody please look into my code and help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't import MySQLdb. Use Django instead.
2. Don't bother connecting to the database directly. Use Django instead.
3. If you are going to create objects from your models, you need to import those. They will take care of importing all of the necessary Django modules, if you have written them correctly.
4. Model.objects.create() is a shorthand for creating a new object and saving it.

Something like this:

```
from myapp.models import EmployeeDetails

def dumpdata():
    userName = 'John'
    designation = 'Software Engineer'
    employeeID = '2312'
    contactNumber = '9495321257'
    project = 'cricket'
    dateOfJoin = '2009-10-10'
    EmployeeDetails.objects.create(userName,designation,employeeID,contactNumber,project,dateOfJoin)
```

Or this (using keyword arguments means that you don't have to remember the exact order of parameters to create the object):

```
EmployeeDetails.objects.create(
    userName='John',
    designation='Software Engineer',
    employeeID='2312',
    contactNumber='9495321257',
    project='cricket',
    dateOfJoin='2009-10-10')
```

You'll have to run that with the Django package on your Python path, and with your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable set correctly. Something like this usually works for me:

```
PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings python my_script.py
```

But that invocation can depend a lot on your system setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ian, I tried that way. After giving the run command, its not returning any error. But the data is not getting inserted.

Comment: Can you add data via the python shell? Run `manage.py shell`, and then do the import and try to create the object; if you can do it that way, then you just need to figure out how to get the script to do the same thing.

Comment: i got an error while entering through python cosole ,"raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'employeeID' cannot be null") "

Comment: That sounds like your columns are declared in a different order than you're presenting them when you create the object. I've added a better method of calling `create()` to the answer; try that to see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [MySQL support for python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) yet?

In case you're on Windows, the simplest would be to use a [precompiled distribution](http://www.codegood.com/archives/4) - this one's limited to Python 2.6. I haven't found any precompiled version for higher Python versions.

Comment: yes i have installed MySQL support for python. And i am working on Ubuntu 10.04